# How to play Non-Steam Windows games on Ubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, wine, games, steam

I've been using Kubuntu 22.04 for a long time and I'm very satisfied, except for Windows games.

I love games a lot, it's my habit of killing time. I would be very grateful if you could help me with this.

I have 2 games that are only playable on Windows. Ragnarok Online and Gods Unchained. I haven't been able to run both games on Kubuntu. Play on Linux / Lutris / Steam Proton / Wine none of them worked. Even if it was another game, I guess I wouldn't be able to install it again.

Is there a guide that will guide me step by step to install these games? What is your advice other than using Windows? (I want to delete Windows, I can't delete it just because of these games)

Comment: Unfortunately, if the authors won’t release it for Linux and you can’t access it via steam or wine, I don’t think you’ll be able to play it in Ubuntu. Might be worth contacting steam to see if they can add those games?

Comment: @Will that looks like an answer. It might be the best answer that appears for several moons.

Comment: @user535733 - thanks - I suppose I didn’t think it was much use to the op!